# Como Vizuializar todos los datos

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Que tal amigos estoy llenado un gridview desde un archivo de excel con 24 columnas en visual basic con asp.net, y si agrega los datos al gridview pero cuando intento pasar a la  Pagina 2 que aparece en la imagen ya no me aparece ningun dato, menciono que es la primera vez que hago este metodo de cargar un gridview desde un archivo de excel (La imagen es solo un pequeña parte solo recorte la parte donde aparecen las paginas que genero la carga de los datos)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo el codigo

```
        Protected Sub CargarExcel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
        CargarExcel.Click
      If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
        Dim archivo As String = Server.MapPath("~/") + FileUpload1.FileName
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(archivo)

        Dim oExcel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim oBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim oSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(archivo)
        oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

        Dim dataTable As New DataTable
        dataTable.Columns.Add("OrdenDeCarga")
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Semana")
        dataTable.Columns.Add("FechaDeEmbarque")
        dataTable.Columns.Add("FechaDeEntrega")
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Codigo")
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Ciclo")
        dataTable.Columns.Add("DueñoDelPredio")
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Zona")
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Municipio")
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Predio")
        dataTable.Columns.Add("TipoDeAgave")
        dataTable.Columns.Add("TipoDeContrato")
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Proveedor")
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Cliente")
      
           Dim fila As Integer = 8
        Dim valorCelda1 As String = oSheet.Cells(fila, 1).Value
        Dim valorCelda2 As String = oSheet.Cells(fila, 2).Value
        Dim valorCelda3 As String = oSheet.Cells(fila, 3).Value
        Dim valorCelda4 As String = oSheet.Cells(fila, 4).Value
        Dim valorCelda5 As String = oSheet.Cells(fila, 5).Value
        Dim valorCelda6 As String = oSheet.Cells(fila, 6).Value
        Dim valorCelda7 As String = oSheet.Cells(fila, 7).Value
        Dim valorCelda8 As String = oSheet.Cells(fila, 8).Value
        Dim valorCelda9 As String = oSheet.Cells(fila, 9).Value
        Dim valorCelda10 As String = oSheet.Cells(fila, 10).Value
        Dim valorCelda11 As String = oSheet.Cells(fila, 11).Value
        Dim valorCelda12 As String = oSheet.Cells(fila, 12).Value
        Dim valorCelda13 As String = oSheet.Cells(fila, 13).Value
     

            While valorCelda1 <> ""
            dataTable.Rows.Add(valorCelda1, valorCelda2, valorCelda3,
                          valorCelda4, valorCelda5, valorCelda6,
                          valorCelda7, valorCelda8, valorCelda9,
                          valorCelda10, valorCelda11, valorCelda12,
                          valorCelda13)
      
            fila += 1
            valorCelda1 = oSheet.Cells(fila, 1).Value
            valorCelda2 = oSheet.Cells(fila, 2).Value
            valorCelda3 = oSheet.Cells(fila, 3).Value
            valorCelda4 = oSheet.Cells(fila, 4).Value
            valorCelda5 = oSheet.Cells(fila, 5).Value
            valorCelda6 = oSheet.Cells(fila, 6).Value
            valorCelda7 = oSheet.Cells(fila, 7).Value
            valorCelda8 = oSheet.Cells(fila, 8).Value
            valorCelda9 = oSheet.Cells(fila, 9).Value
            valorCelda10 = oSheet.Cells(fila, 10).Value
            valorCelda11 = oSheet.Cells(fila, 11).Value
            valorCelda12 = oSheet.Cells(fila, 12).Value
            valorCelda13 = oSheet.Cells(fila, 13).Value
           

        End While
       
        oBook.Close()
        oExcel.Quit()

        GridView1.DataSource = dataTable
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```